# How to set up django user permissions with one user having multiple permissions?

Tags: django, django-models, user-permissions, django-users

I've got the following idea. One user can be in multiple companies. The user has different permissions in every company that he or she is in. 
The example below doesn't work, because one user would always have the same permissions.

How should I set up my User Model that one User has a different permission in every company?

That's what I've tried so far:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    hourly_wage = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, default=8.50)

    class Meta:
        permissions = (("is_general", "Can add people to his company and see everything"),
                       ("is_captain", "Can add/edit/delete everything"),
                       ("is_staff", "Can add/edit/delete jobs"),
                       ("is_programmer", "Can do what he or she wants to do"))

    def clean(self):
        self.username = self.username.lower()


class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="companies")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "companies"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define a **model for the `ManyToManyField`** through which the many to many relation flows.

So instead of:

```
+---------+ M      N +-------------+ M      N +------------+
| Company |----------| User        |----------| Permission |
+---------+          +-------------+          +------------+
                     | permissions |
                     +-------------+
```

We thus write it like:

```
+---------+ 1      N +-------------+ M      1 +------+
| Company |----------| UserCompany |----------| User |
+---------+          +-------------+          +------+
                            | M
                            |
                            | N
                     +------------+
                     | Permission |
                     +------------+
```

We can do this with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

class User(AbstractUser):

    def clean(self):
        self.username = self.username.lower()


class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='app.CompanyUser', related_name="companies")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "companies"


class CompanyUser(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey('app.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.ForeignKey('app.Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hourly_wage = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, default=8.50)
    permissions = models.ManyToManyField(Permission, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You probably want to shift other logic to the *through* model. For example the`hourly_wage` is probably also related to a (`User`, `Company`)-pair, and not specific to a `User` itself.

You can thus add permissions to the `UserCompany` with:

```
someusercompany.permissions.add(some_permission)
```

Then you check if a `UserCompany` has a permission with:

```
CompanyUser.objects.filter(
    user=some_user,
    company=some_company,
    some_permission=some_permission
).exists()
```

See more about this in the [*documentation about **`through`** parameter* [django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through).

Comment: I've got this structure now, but how can I assign permissions to a CompanyUser instance?

Comment: @Daniel: sorry, this will require some changes, updated the answer.